# Flutter Tabbar Text in two lines with different styles

Tags: android, ios, flutter, frontend

I have a question regarding a Tabbar in flutter.
I want to create the following tabbar, which has a bigger number and a smaller text underneath it. When selected, it should be in a bigger font. [The design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShzVS.png).
It tried many ways. But the one, that looked the closest to the design, was, when I used a construction with a column and two separate Text-Widgets.

But with columns and text, it ignores the selected and unselected Label style, because I needed to style them individually.
So now it looks nice, but there is no indication on what tab you are (I don't want to use the normal indicator).
Is there a solution for it?

I tried the following code:

```
TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1?.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                unselectedLabelStyle:
                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1?.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "12",
                          style:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1?.copyWith(
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                  ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Abonniert",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "35",
                          style:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1?.copyWith(
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                  ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Fragen",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "50",
                          style:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1?.copyWith(
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                  ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Contacts",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning style on the `Text` widgets instead of defining label styles like this:

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  const Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Sample> createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final tabs = <Widget>[
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          Text("12"),
          Text("Abonniert"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          Text("35"),
          Text("Fragen"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Column(
        children: const [
          Text("50"),
          Text("Contacts"),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ];

  late final controller = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: this);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: TabBar(
            controller: controller,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            labelStyle: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .displayLarge
                ?.copyWith(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            unselectedLabelStyle: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .displayLarge
                ?.copyWith(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            tabs: tabs,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```